# wget and curl much slower when invoked from bash script

Tags: performance, bash, curl, download, wget

I'm writing a little automation script and I need to download one file. When I use curl or wget directly from bash, the average dl speed is about 3MB/s. However, when I invoke it from the bash script, the download speed drops to 300kB/s. It happens for both curl and wget.

I'm on OS X, with bash 3.2.48, wget 1.12 and curl 7.19.7

EDIT: the script - it's just this snippet so far. I just tried it and found that issue...

```
#!/bin/bash
CURVER=1.0
VERSION=1.2


if [ ${VERSION//\./} -gt ${CURVER//\./} ]; then
    echo "There is a new version available!"

    wget -O /tmp/dl.dmg $DOWNLOAD

fi
```

Comment: Show us the script - without it there's no way to tell!

Comment: I'm assuming you set the variable `$DOWNLOAD` elsewhere. There's no need to escape the dot in your brace expansions and the final slash isn't necessary. I can't see anything in your snippet that would account for a slowdown. Is `nice` or `ionice` or something similar in effect in some way?

Comment: Nothing strange that I can see, except for the unknown contents of `$DOWNLOAD`. How are you running your script? Is it possible, for example, that any environment variables (e.g. `http_proxy`) could be different inside the script?

Comment: Yeah, $DOWNLOAD is usually set, just forgot to copy it...
I don't use any proxy nor nice.

Answer (score 0):

EXTREMELY WEIRD!

Are you executing the script with the same user than the one you use to try it from command line?

Maybe the script is ran by a user with some type of policy that slowdown connection?